# Deleting every .txt file in folder and subfolder when dragged on to .vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a simple VBS script which deletes every .txt file in the drag/dropped folder and subfolders, however, it doesn't seem to work, even though it doesn't throw any errors.

I'm new to VBS, so it is probably something obvious.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, strFolder, objFile, objFolder, Folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get the folder dropped onto our script...
strFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder strFolder

Sub DoFolder(strFolder)
    ' Check each file...
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
        If Right(objFile.name, 4) = ".txt" Then
            objFSO.DeleteFile(strFolder & "\" & objFile.name)
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).SubFolders
        DoFolder objFolder.Path
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me!

Comment: Huh, yeah it does... Uhm, but if I change the ".txt" to ".v", which it should be, it doesn't delete the ".v" files, how can that be?

Comment: Because you're probably checking the last **four** characters against the _two_ characters ".v". Also, you might want to take case sensitivity into account.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!